# Rest-assured. get value from another value

Tags: java, rest, response, rest-assured

I have a json response something like this:

```
"results": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "YYY",
      "shortName": "Y"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "XXX",
      "shortName": "X"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "ZZZ",
      "shortName": "Z"
    }
  ]
```

I want to get id value when I send name value. For example if name = ZZZ return me id value in this case 3 using rest assured

Comment: What is Rest Assured?
Rest Assured enables you to test REST APIs using java libraries, after getting the JSON values u can just use JSONObject or object mapper to get what u want.

Comment: you are right, I mean with JsonPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json path `json-path-2.9.0` with `rest-assured`

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.path.json.JsonPath.from;
```

below JsonPath query

```
from(response).getList("results.findAll { it.name=='ZZZ' }.id").toString() //returns 3

from(response).getList("results.findAll { it.name=='XXX' }.id").toString() //returns 2
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks. the followign code was the solution:  Data.getData().forEach(s -> {
    s.setID(response.jsonPath().getString("results.findAll { it.name=='"+s.getID()+"' }.id").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]",""));